# Is it possible to find $p-1$ natural numbers $n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+p-1$?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Is it possible to find $p-1$ natural numbers $n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+p-1$ such that the sum of the squares of these numbers is divisible by the sum of these numbers?

We can rewrite any list of an even number of consecutive naturals as $\ldots,y-1,y,y+1,y+2,\ldots$ and thus the given list as $x-\frac{p-3}{2},\ldots,x,\ldots,x+\frac{p-1}{2},x+\frac{p-1}{2}$. Then the sum is $(p-1)x+\frac{p-3}{2}$, while I am not sure what the sum of the squares is but someone else got $\frac{p-1}{2}x+\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{p-3}{3}\frac{p-2}{2}+(\frac{p-1}{2})^2$. I am not sure how they got that. Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: The sum of squares cannot be right because it has to have a term in $x^2$

Comment: $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2=3(1+2+3+4)$; $12^2+\dots+21^2=17(12+\dots+21)$.

Comment: If $3\mid 2n+1$ then $1+2+3+\ldots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ divides $1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. We can take $n = p-1$ where $p$ is any prime satisfying $p\equiv 2\mod 3$.

Comment: @almagest: nice equalities as it is so for $1+1=2$ but, so what concerning the question? The first example just say that for the particular numbers 1,2,3,4 the property is not satisfied for $p=5$; similarly for $p=11$

Comment: @user19405892 What exactly are you asking for? Winther has showed that for $p=2\bmod3$ the first $p-1$ natural numbers have the sum of their squares divisible by their sum. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @almagest: The question is asking for any $p$ if it is possible. So we must show a contradiction.

Comment: @user19405892 Well, it is possible for $p=2\bmod 3$. Do you know of any other $p$ for which it is possible?

Comment: For the general question we have
$$S^{(2)}_{n,p-1} = \left[\frac{(p-2)p}{6 (p+2n)}+\frac{2n+p}{2}\right]S^{(1)}_{n,p-1}$$
so the question boils down to: given $p$ can be find an integer $n$ such that $\frac{(p-2)p}{6 (p+2n)}+\frac{2n+p}{2}$ is an integer.

Comment: @Winther that is equivalent to $3(p+2n)$ dividing $p(p-2)$. If $p=1\bmod3$ then $p(p-2)$ is not a multiple of 3. So you have done it!

Comment: @Winther I don't get how you got that recursion.

Comment: I used that $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so  $\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p-1} i = a_{n+p-1} - a_n$. Likewise since $b_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ so  $\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+p-1} i^2 = b_{n+p-1} - b_n$. The rest is just algebra, i.e. evaluating $\frac{b_{n+p-1}-b_n}{a_{n+p-1}-a_n}$ and simplifying.

Comment: @Winther I still don't see how you get the recursion.

Comment: @Winther Also, I don't understand your notation. What does $S_{n,p-1}$ mean?

Comment: Above the notation I used was: $S^{(1)}_{n,k} \equiv \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} i$ and $S^{(2)}_{n,k} \equiv \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} i^2$ (and taking $k=p-1$ this corresponds to the two sums you have in the question text).

Comment: @Winther How did almagest determine proving that $\left[\dfrac{(p-2)p}{6(p+2n)}+\dfrac{2n+p}{2}\right]$ is an integer is equivalent to showing that $3(p+2n)$ divides $p(p-2)$?

Comment: First put everything on one fraction: $\frac{p(p-2) + 3(p+2n)(2n+p)}{6(p+2n)}$. The denominator has a factor of $3$ so if the number is an integer then the numerator has to be divisible by $3$. The second term is OK but for the first term to be divisible by $3$ we need $p$ to be on the form $3A + 2$ for some integer $A$. If $p$ is on the form $3A+1$ then you can check that $p(p-2)$ is not divisible by $3$ (and $p$ cannot be on the form $3A$ as this is not a prime unless $A=1$)

Comment: @RossMillikan where $x^2$?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: each term has an $x$ in it.  When they are squared, these become $x^2$ and there are $p-1$ of them, so the sum of squares must contain a term $(p-1)x^2$  There will be a cross term that includes $x$.   [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+(x-(p-3%2B2i)%2F2)%5E2+%7Bi,0,p-2%7D) gets $(p-1) (13 p^2-2 p (12 x+31)+3 (2 x+5)^2)/12$